# Stop music from in flash from javascript event

Tags: javascript, flash

I am attempting to stop the music inside of my flash swf that I have loaded in the page

```
<object id="FlashControl1" type="application/x-shockwave-flash"
data="Flash/Preloader%20-%20Splash.swf" width="980px" height="316px">
<param name="movie" value="Flash/Preloader%20-%20Splash.swf" />
<param name="wmode" value="Transparent" />
<param name="quality" value="High" />
<param name="play" value="True" />
<param name="loop" value="False" />
<param name="menu" value="False" />
<param name="scale" value="Exactfit" />
<param name="flashvars" value="name="FlashControl1"" />
<img src="Images/Banner/Main_Banner.jpg" alt="" width="980px" height="316px" />
</object>
```

I have a button that loads a modal popup with a silverlight video and I would like the audio to stop by execuding the SoundMixer.stop(); command.

I have yet to find a solution on google

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your Flash file, you must have the following function:

```
function stopSound():void {
    SoundMixer.stop();
}
```

Then, you must make it available for JavaScript calls

```
ExternalInterface.addCallback('stopSound', stopSound);
```

In your JavaScript code you must have this simple function that selects your swf:

```
function getFlashMovie(movieName) 
{
    var isIE = navigator.appName.indexOf("Microsoft") != -1;
    return (isIE) ? window[movieName] : document[movieName];
}
```

And when you want to stop the sounds in your movie, you just call the function you've previously made available in the swf, from JavaScript:

```
movie = getFlashMovie('your-movie-name');
movie.stopSound();
```

That should do it. For more info on ExternalInterface.addCallback, check out [the Adobe AS3  Language Refrence page](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html#addCallback()).

Comment: Message: 'undefined' is null or not an object
I am using the following to generate my flash file
<Bewise:FlashControl MovieUrl="Preloader - Splash.swf" ID="FlashControl1" runat="server" Width="980px" Height="316px" WMode="Transparent" XHTMLcompliant="True" Scale="Exactfit" SwLiveConnect="True"/>

Comment: function test() {
    movie = document.getElementById('FlashControl1');
    movie.stopSound();
}

ended up working.  thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
function test() {
movie = document.getElementById('FlashControl1');
movie.stopSound();}
```

this worked :)

Comment: Make sure you check it on all browsers. I remember I had some problems with getElementById, but I don't remember exactly why I didn't use it in the end.

Answer (score -1):

I tried lot of things e.g. `$("object").stop();`

nothing worked for IE.

Then I came up with this dirty solution.
I put this whole object inside a ***div***

then in javascript

```
document.getElementById("outerdiv").innerHTML="";
```

boom ... works like a charm...

Comment: What should `$("object").stop();` do? That stops jQuery animations and has nothing to do with sound or flash.